# add new column if not exists in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi Im using this query in sqlite

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STU_REMAINDER( REG_NO VARCHAR(15), REM_ID INTEGER, REM_DATETIME DATETIME, DETAILS VARCHAR(500),STATUS INTEGER )');
```

I want to add column SCH_ID in this table, if not exist in this column. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer using a GUI Firefox addon Sqlite Manager to work with Sqlite database. You can download it from below url

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

You can view queries in it too when you add or alter table.

Comment: Hi Sir Thank you. but i want need the mobile running time its add column only one time and next time its show SQL ERROR code 5 I need this solution